# I can not find a way to test the Cordova mobile app

Tags: cordova, testing

How can I make Unit tests for cordova mobile app? Can someone give me some details about this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I used Appium with chromedriver and I cannot get it to work